# How to wait for auth state to load on the client before fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Recently I stumbled across the useAuth and useRequireAuth hooks: https://usehooks.com/useRequireAuth/. They are incredibly useful when it comes to client-side authentication. However, what's the correct way for waiting until auth data is available to fetch some other data? I've come up with the following code:

```
const Page = () => {
// makes sure user is authenticated but asynchronously, redirects if not authenticated, short screen-flash
useRequireAuth()

// actual user object in state, will be updated when firebase auth state changes
const user = useStoreState((state) => state.user.user);


if (!user) {
  return <div>Loading</div>
}


useEffect(() => {
if (user) {
  fetchSomeDataThatNeedsAuth();
}
}, [user]);


return (
    <h1>Username is: {user.name}</h1>
)
```

}

Is this a "good" way to do it or can this be improved somehow? It feels very verbose and needs to be repeated for every component that needs auth.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. The thing you could improve is that your `useRequireAuth()` could return the user, but that's up to you.

Additionally, you probably should check if user is defined before rendering `user.name`.